# Auto HotKey, Toggle: Hold Shift, Click and release LButton every second

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make an AutoHotkey script that holds <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and while it's holding it I need the mouse to click and release every second. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
Home::
KeyDown := !KeyDown
If KeyDown
    SendInput {Shift down}, Click, Sleep 2000
Else
    SendInput {Shift up}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop after a certain amount of time behavior is best implemented with a [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) function invoking a [Subroutine](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm).

Additionally, since your script holds down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, you would need to also have the hotkey be invoked whenever <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> is pressed as well, so that it can be turned off.

---

Final Code:

```
Home::
+Home:: ;Alternative hotkey definition that invokes on Shift+Home
    KeyDown := !KeyDown
    if (KeyDown){
        SendInput {Shift down}
        gosub, clickSubroutine ;To trigger the first click immediately
        SetTimer, clickSubroutine, 1000 ;To trigger clicks after every 1000 ms (1 second)
    }
    else{
        SendInput {Shift up}
        SetTimer, clickSubroutine, Off ;Turn off the clickSubroutine Loop
    }
Return

clickSubroutine:
    Click
return
```

Comment: Looks great, but I have two nitpicks: 1) The `Shift`+`Home` hotkey definition is redundant because unless you specify otherwise, AutoHotkey automatically captures the "capitalized" version of each hotkey, which includes when `Shift` is being held down.  This is documented [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap).  and 2) I think some indentation would make it much easier to read.  Other than that, it's exactly how I would do it.

Comment: Responding to the nitpicks @CharlieArmstrong: 1. While `KeyDown` was true, I wasn't able to trigger the hotkey before I added the `Shift`+`Home` hotkey definition. I get what you are saying, but I don't think that it applies to the `Home` key in particular given that there is no standard "Capitalized" version of this key.  2. Indentation updated; thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting.  I just copied your code directly into a new AHK script, removed the `+Home::` line, and it worked just like it's supposed to.  Maybe it's a system/version dependent behavior?  And the indentation looks nice :)